# SQL Server : update old ID to new ID (SELF JOIN in UPDATE)

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server table, and column category IDs (`kategori`) needs to be updated.

I need to find `id_old` first and update as new `id`  instead:

[image]

How can I do this in batch with a T-SQL statement?

Comment: you can do it using `SELF JOIN`

Comment: yes, I need to use SELF JOIN in UPDATE. But how can I use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `SELF JOIN`. You need to use a different `alias` on the table.

```
UPDATE t2
SET    kategori = t1.id
FROM   yourtable t1
       INNER JOIN yourtable t2 ON t1.id_old = t2.kategori
WHERE  t2.kategory <> 0   -- not sure but you might need this condition
```

Comment: Msg 1013, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
The objects "moduls" and "moduls" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them.
----------
UPDATE moduls
SET    kategori = moduls.id
FROM   moduls
       INNER JOIN moduls ON moduls.id_old = moduls.kategori
WHERE  moduls.kategori <> 0

Comment: you need to use table alias as what I did in my query

Comment: UPDATE t2
SET    kategori = t1.id
FROM   moduls t1
       INNER JOIN moduls t2 ON t1.id_old = t2.kategori
WHERE  t2.kategori <> 0